# Don't display element label, but display element in a nested html form

Tags: html, css

On a php-generated site, I have HTML source code like

```
<label for="fieldName">
     Label Text
    <input id="fieldName" class="textField" (...) name="fieldName"></input>
</label>
```

My problem is that I want to set `display: none` for the label text, but the input field should still be displayed. Only CSS is available, I can't change the HTML structure.

I tried setting `display: none`for the label node, and afterwards `display: block !important`for the input field, but that did not work. Neither can I reference the text itself, because it is not included in `<p>`or anything like this. The only solutions I found were about a label node using the `for:` attribute, but where there input node was not contained inside the label node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, there is no way to make a child element of display:none visible... so you can try to use the visibility attribute.... disadvantage is, that the width of the hidden element stays.. because of that, it made the input overlap.

hope that helps as a starting point!

```css
label {
  visibility: hidden;
}
input {
  left: 0;
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<label for="simpleQuery">
  Label Text
  <input id="simpleQuery" class="textField" (...) name="simpleQuery"></input>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped solve my problem. I used `visibility` as you recommended and reduced the font size to get rid of the height of the hidden element.

Answer (score 0):

You just get your element out of the label tag ([as it should be](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp))

```
<label for="simpleQuery">Label Text</label>
<input id="simpleQuery" class="textField" (...) name="simpleQuery"></input>
```

Comment: There is no reason that an `<input>`, or `<textarea>`, element should not be nested within a `<label>` element; it's perfectly valid – so long as there's only the one `<input>` (or `<textarea>`) and no other interactive content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this html structure that is also valid:

```
   <label for="fieldName">Label Text</label>
   <input id="fieldName" class="textField" (...) name="fieldName"></input>
```

and will be able to hide the label and not the form field.

Comment: Not "also" valid. The presented markup in the question is semantically inacurrate.

Comment: You are right but I have seen plenty of that in older code... not the first time at all

Comment: What's the "*semantically inaccurate*" part of the html in the question – with the exception of the invalid closing `</input>` tag?